# Cannot run Great Expectations quickstart

Tags: python, great-expectations

I am trying to use Great Expectations (Python data quality framework). I ran the quickstart after installing GX on WSL2 and Python 3.9.16

The quickstart code can be found here: https://docs.greatexpectations.io/docs/tutorials/quickstart/

I am getting an error at the last statement:

`context.convert_to_file_context()`

`AttributeError: 'FileDataContext' object has no attribute 'convert_to_file_context'`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

When you run the demo for first time the `context = gx.get_context()` creates `EphemeralDataContext` that has the method `convert_to_file_context()`.

*Note the `great_expectations/` folder that has been created.*

---

When you run the demo next time `context = gx.get_context()` creates `FileDataContext` that doesn't have this method.

You can add a check for the type to the code, for example:

```py
from great_expectations.data_context.data_context import EphemeralDataContext

# ...

if isinstance(context, EphemeralDataContext):
    context.convert_to_file_context()
```

Answer (score 0):

This should be fixed when you upgrade to the latest version of GX - 0.16.5

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).